# Reputation points decreased without downvotes / negative points

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, reputation-history, lost-reputation

I'm using Stack Overflow. I got 35 points there yesterday. Today 2/1 points were subtracted from the total (i.e. 33/34 points), but downvotes / negative points are not visible in my reputation history.
What's happening here?

> [image]

Comment: What do you mean by "2/1 points were decreased"?  Did you get any points for suggested edits in the past?  If you edit a post and get the 2 points for it, you lose those if the post is deleted.

Comment: no.. not like that.. yesterday my reputation was 1222.. today when i opened i saw its 1221 points.. this happened few times previously too.. at that time 2 points were decreased.. without any negative points visible on my rep.

Comment: Did you downvote any answers during that time?

Comment: no.. i didn't..

Comment: @Kiran add a screenshot of [your reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3401528/kiran?tab=reputation), we can only see the part of the history that is public.

Comment: and make sure "show removed posts" is checked!

Comment: @cupcake.. i added screenshot..

Comment: @Nick: can u tell me how to check removed posts..

Comment: No, [it's a checkbox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OT4MD.png).

Comment: OK.. Thanks Nick.. this helped me..

Comment: Use the Time tab, just like I linked to in my original comment, or otherwise expand the arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't verify my suspicion without mod privileges, but since [it seems you didn't know](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236480/reputation-points-decreased-without-downvotes-negative-points#comment775295_236480), removed posts don't show up in [your rep history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3401528/kiran?tab=reputation) unless you mark the little box at the bottom of the page. Compare:

> [image] . . . **vs.** . . . [image]

Since this checkbox also affects the total rep score displayed next to the date, it's quite a sneaky way to lose rep. Don't worry about it if this happens to you though; it's a matter of site maintenance, not anything you're doing wrong. E.g., if you successfully suggest an edit to a post that gets deleted anyway, you'll lose the 2 rep you gained for that edit. If on the same day another post that you downvoted gets removed, you'll get 1 reputation back from the downvote you cast. That could result in having a net -1 rep due to removed posts, which you'd have to check the box to see.

Comment: Thanks.. just excited to know about this too.. do we get points for down vote if question is not related to particular topic?

Comment: If you downvoted an answer that gets removed, you get that reputation point back from that answer's removal. Topic doesn't matter; all that matters is that you had a downvote on it when it was removed, and that downvoting actually cost you something. You don't get points for downvoting answers that get removed from per-site metas, because those downvotes are free. The rep change is a return to the neutral state before you had any interaction with the removed post.

Comment: BTW, I posted [a similar tip in response to some related confusion on Cross Validated](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/2039/32036) a while ago. A feature request to make this button a little more obvious might be in order...